# Azure blob storage data lake service client how to get folders and files in sorted format based on type in paginated response

Tags: asp.net, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-explorer

Here is my code I'm using initialized data service client to get the storage blob containers folders and files.

[image]

However, while iterating through paginated responses I'm not getting data in a sorted format.
I want all the folders/directories to appear on the first pages and then files at the end.

[image]

It would be helpful if someone has an idea of how this can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Apoorva petkar Could you provide enough code and Update question with code format?

Answer (score 0):

*Fetching Files and folders from Blob Storage in Pagination*

1. *Create a storage account*
   [image]
2. *Create a file share account*
   [image]
3. *Create a directory / folder in fileshare*
   [image]
4. *Use the Connection string of the storage account,  fileshare     name and folder name in the below code*

   ```
        string connectionString = "Connection-String";
        CloudStorageAccount cloud_StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudFileClient cloud_FileClient = cloud_StorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
        CloudFileShare cloud_FileShare = cloud_FileClient.GetShareReference("FileShare");
        CloudFileDirectory root_Directory = cloud_FileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
        CloudFileDirectory file_Directory = root_Directory.GetDirectoryReference("Directory_Name");
        List<IListFileItem> files = Get_Files_Directory(file_Directory);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in files)
        {

            SampleData s = new SampleData();
            s.ID = i+1;
            s.FileName = ((Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File.CloudFile)item).Name;
            s.FolderName = ((Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File.CloudFile)item).SnapshotQualifiedUri.LocalPath;

            _sampleDataList.Add(s);

        }``
   ```

*Code Execution*
[image]

*The below is the list of sorted files in the pagination*
*Page1*
[image]

*Page2*
[image]

Comment: this is for Azure files. I'm using Azure blob storage.